# If url ends with ' then show post

Tags: sql, url, code-injection

I have a website, let's say that my site is `example.com`.

I would like to show a post if anyone tries to sql injection it. For example if the link is `example.com/?portofolio=1` and they type `example.com/?portofolio=1'` then I would like to show a post/page (refer them to another post) instead of database information (if they get any). Everytime they type `'` at the end of every url.

Comment: use command parameters and catch exceptions

Comment: If your code is susceptible to that kind of thing - you're doing it wrong. Use e.g pdo withprepared statements.

Comment: thank you, i am novice to that kind of thing, i will google what you typed and i'll try to find a solution. Thank you again

Comment: You've found out about one way that SQL Injection can be performed. But it's not the only way. So it would be better to a) use a comprehensive solution that means you don't have to think about it and b) it's probably better to explicitly validate - e.g. if you want `portofolio` to only contain a number, check for *that* rather than trying to blacklist certain characters. Also, most SQL injection attacks won't have a `'` at the *end* of the string

Comment: A typical attempt at SQL injection would be e.g. `example.com/?portofolio=1' or 1=1 --` - note that the `'` is **not** at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to *show* that page - that depends on the language and/or framework you are using. This can usually be done with a [redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection), though some frameworks allow rendering a different page for the same URL.

If you are asking how to *detect* SQL injections - that depends on how your code works. Different codes will have different ways to inject SQL. If you are going to go through the trouble of figuring out all the SQL vulnerabilities in your code, and code some rules to try and catch them - wouldn't it be better to remove those vulnerabilities? It'll be easier too - usually the answer is to use SQL parameters instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: Thank you for reply, i don't have sql injections on my website nether other forms of valuns, but their beeing content always added, so i want to make sure